# error: unknown type name 'constexpr' when compiling using g++ on mac

Tags: c++, macos, compilation, g++, constexpr

I'm trying to use `constexpr` for the first time in C++ on Mac. I am using sublime text but am compiling through terminal. Here is the command I'm using to compile: 
`g++ -o helloworld helloworld.cpp`
Let me make something clear: **I KNOW THIS QUESTION IS A DUPLICATE**, but all the other questions were using xCode or VS Code, and since I'm using a text editor, not an IDE, then those answers don't apply to me. I know that people will ask for this, so here is what happens when I run the following command:

```
g++ --version
//...
Apple clang version 11.0.3 (clang-1103.0.32.29)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19.4.0
Thread model: posix
```

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>

constexpr int cube(int n){
    return n*n*n;
}

int main(){

    constexpr int hello = 2*cube(5);
    auto niceNum = 69.420;
    std::cout << hello << niceNum << "\n";

}
```

Here is the output:

```
helloworld.cpp:3:1: error: unknown type name 'constexpr'
constexpr int cube(int n){
^
helloworld.cpp:9:2: error: unknown type name 'constexpr'
        constexpr int hello = 2*cube(5);
        ^
helloworld.cpp:10:2: warning: 'auto' type specifier is a C++11 extension
      [-Wc++11-extensions]
        auto niceNum = 69.420;
        ^
```

(There is also an error with the `auto` keyword, which I'm assuming is related to the `constexpr` issue, since they're both unique to C++, meaning they're not included in C) Thanks.

Comment: Add `-std=c++11` to your compile command.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen why? what does this do?

Comment: It makes gcc compile using C++11 standard (which adds e.g. `constexpr` and `auto` keywords)

Comment: Your compiler uses C++98 per default. `constexpr` is a C++11 feature. You have to enable it.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen will check if this works. If so, please put it up as the answer.

Comment: https://opensource.apple.com/source/clang/clang-703.0.31/src/tools/clang/www/cxx_status.html

Comment: @Yksisarvinen It works! please put it up as an answer